# Using trusted certificate key and crt files to enable TLS in Sendmail

Tags: ssl, sendmail, tls

I have an SSL certificate and key from a trusted CA (not self-signed). This gives me the following files on a Fedora system:

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.crt
/etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.csr
/etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.key
```

My sendmail.mc file contains these lines:

```
define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.crt')dnl
define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.key')dnl
```

Note that I don't have any `.pem` files that are commonly shown in examples of how to get TLS working in sendmail.

When I start sendmail, I get this error:

```
Aug 22 15:10:17 cs sendmail[23424]: STARTTLS=server, error: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(/etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.key) failed
```

I assume the reason for the error is it is looking for a `.pem` file, but I only have a `.key` file to give. Should I create a `.pem` file? If so, how do I do it from my existing files? When I try to run `make mydomain.pem` it wants to create a CSR from scratch.

### Solution

As pointed out below, there was a password on the key file. I removed it using the `openssl` command and sendmail was able to load the file. I also needed to start `saslauthd` to get it all working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks correct, the .pem file is the certificate or public key and can also be .cer or .crt as far as I'm aware. See [this similar post](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file-f) for more information.

Regarding the actual error, does the key have a password associated with it? Do you definitely have the files the right away around? The .key should start with `---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---` and the .crt should start with `---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---`

Comment: Yes, there's a password on it. It's the same certificate used for the web server. Is that the problem?