# Converting .cer to .pem errors

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I realize that there are multiple posts about converting .cer to .pem, but none actually mention issues regarding the coversion. I have a cert named Cert.cer (original, I know) that I'm trying to convert to Cert_PEM.pem using the following command:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in Cert.cer -out Cert_PEM.pem
```

In doing so I run into this error:

```
13892:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
13892:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509
```

I have some knowledge of certs, SSL and encryption, but this goes beyond the current scope of it.

**EDIT:** Here are the first 4 lines of the cert:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC6DCCAdACAQMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgYQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQ4wDAYD
VQQIEwVUZXhhczEPMA0GA1UEBxMGQXVzdGluMS4wLAYDVQQLEyVNb3RpdmUgU2Vy
dmVyIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZNb3RpdmUxEzAR
```

Any help would be excellent!

Comment: Please provide the first few lines of the `.cer` file, it may not be in the format you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a PEM-encoded .cer file. Converting may be as easy as *changing the file extension*. [SSL-file formats are legion](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file/9717#9717) and der-encoding is actually not that common.

A general rule of thumb is:

- If looks like base64 encoding, it's probably PEM-encoded.
- If it looks like cat-ing a binary file, it's probably DER-encoded.

Comment: I was thinking it was something like that... But I didn't want to be the guy asking if changing the file extension would work. I guess this is another one of those "The only stupid question is the one unasked" moments.