# OpenSSL: --keyout option: create .key or .key.pem files?

Tags: linux, openssl, truenas

The tutorial I'm following to create and sign certificates bounces between creating `.key` and `.key.pem` files with the `-keyout` option.

For example: `master-ca.key.pem` and `openvpn-ica.key` and again `vpn-server.key.pem`.

Does it matter and is there a standard?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered before. See this post for a great explanation: [What is a Pem file and how does it differ from other OpenSSL Generated Key File Formats?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file#9717)

Comment: Thank you, I saw that.  A .pem is a just container and it says it doesn't really matter.  But as far as readability and best practices go, which way is it more typically created?

Comment: As stated in this post, *.key is typically used for the private key, *.pem for the certificate (chain).